# How to upload batch objects in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage and Java, I need to upload 1000 objects to GCS in Batch.

This is the documentation that GCS provide

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob_name");
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(UTF_8));
```

But it is only for one object, I was looking for a batch function but I did not find it, thus I have to upload object by object using a for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none yet.  You can read about the existing backlogged feature request here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2351